# Migrated from git to team server; still getting git errors

Tags: git, version-control, repository

We just migrated from git to Team Server. It seems to have gone smoothly. But I'm still getting this error message from git:

[git error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ezc.png)

How can I configure my source control to stop looking for a git repository?

Comment: Perhaps uninstall git?

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a reference somewhere in the project files that still points to Git Repository, which I guess needs to be removed manually, even though the migration has gone smoothly, it doesn't mean that all the files are updated! Worth a shot...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there has `.git` folder in your project directory. If not, you need to reset or just clone for a new one.

```
git clone <your new repository URL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to migrate git to VSTS/TFS.

First you need to create an empty git repo on VSTS/TFS. Then use any of below ways:

#### Option 1: add remote for your local git repo

```
# In your local remote
git remote add origin <URL for VSTS/TFS empty git repo>
git push -u origin master
# If you have other branches, still use git push -u origin branchname
```

#### Option 2: use visual studio

In team explorer -> click add for local repo -> select your local path -> Add -> double click the local repo to open it in VS -> Settings -> Repository Settings -> add remote -> input VSTS/TFS git repo URL fir fetch -> save -> publish branch -> push.

[image]